# How to have an option enabling other options in Boost Program Options without using variables?

Tags: c++, boost-program-options

I use program options to parse the command line options of my application.

I have several options like -Ox, -Oy, -Oz, ... and I want to have a super option -Oall that enables Ox and Oy and another -Osub that enables Oz and Ow.

Is there a way to do that using Boost Program Options ?

At first, I wanted to check the value of Oall and then manually enables Ox and Oy, but it is not possible to edit values after the parsing.

I want to avoid using variables to store the values of Ox, Oy, because I can have a lot of theses options.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to avoid having variables for `Ox`, `Oy`, and `Oz`, how then do you plan on accessing their values?  In other words, how do you plan on triggering the logic associated with those options when they're set individually?

Comment: I wanted to say options.count("Ox")

Comment: Understood. But, there isn't a way to link the occurrence of one parameter with another in `program_options`. However, you could adapt the method of @CharlesB, so that whenever you checked `options.count("Ox")` you also check `options.count("Oall")`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do, but how ? I found no way to edit a variable's value. All the functions of variables_map return const references and I found no way to edit way after parsing.

Comment: That's not what I mean. Instead of `if (options.count("Ox")>0)` use `if (options.count("Ox")>0 || options.count("Oall")>0)`.

Comment: Ah, yes, this is a solution, but with that, I will have a lot of boilerplate code for every option.... For that, I prefer CharlesB solution.

Comment: Have you considered a [custom notifier](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost/program_options/typed_value.html#id969982-bb)? You could then have the `-OAll` code execute the code for the other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this more in your program's logic so I doubt Program Options provide this.
Simply use

```
if (Oall)
{Ox = Oy = Oz = true;}
```

and such

Comment: This works, but with this solution I have to use variables mapping each option and I want to avoid this case if possible.

Comment: At last, it seems that is the best solution to use. Thanks